# Complicated Join in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one master table and 5 child table called

```
@POWER_CHILD, @AUDIO_CHILD, @RESISTOR_CHILD, @CAPACITOR_CHILD, @INDUCTOR_CHILD
```

I need to pull data only when there is an match with child table but any column contain blank i.e no data in master table

That will be treated as valid and appear in the output.

I did `Inner Join`, but no luck. How can I handle blank, so I thought to ask to experts.

Kindly don't treat as basic fundamental question. please share your thoughts.

DDL:

```
DECLARE @MASTER TABLE
(
PowerAmplifierID VARCHAR (50),  
AudioAmplifierID VARCHAR (50),  
ResistorID   VARCHAR (50),
CapacitorID  VARCHAR (50),
InductorID   VARCHAR (50),
Years  VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @MASTER
    SELECT '24456', '5392','',  '2190', '10',   '1959' UNION ALL
    SELECT '24456', '', '',     '8888', '29',   '1959' UNION ALL
    SELECT '30583', '4233', '', '2190', '56',   '1959' UNION ALL
    SELECT '24455', '333333',   '','2190','10', '1958' UNION ALL
    SELECT '696969',    '7879', '1xt','5000','29',  '2015' UNION ALL
    SELECT '24456', '5392', '', '2190', '29',   '1959' UNION ALL
    SELECT '24455', '4233', '', '2190', '56',   '1959' 

DECLARE @POWER_CHILD TABLE
(
PowerAmplifierID VARCHAR (50),  
PowerAmplifier VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @POWER_CHILD
    SELECT '24456', 'Class A Power Amplifiers' UNION ALL
    SELECT '24455', 'Class B Power Amplifiers'

DECLARE @AUDIO_CHILD TABLE
(
AudioAmplifierID VARCHAR (50),
AudioAmplifier VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @AUDIO_CHILD
    SELECT '5392'   ,'Transconductance' UNION ALL
    SELECT '4233'   ,'Transresistance' UNION ALL
    SELECT '7879',  'Vacuum-tube'

DECLARE @RESISTOR_CHILD TABLE
(
ResistorID  VARCHAR (50),
Resistor VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @RESISTOR_CHILD
    SELECT '1xt',   'Thick film' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2xt',   'Metal film' UNION ALL
    SELECT '3xt',   'Wirewound' 

DECLARE @CAPACITOR_CHILD TABLE
(
CapacitorID VARCHAR (50),
Capacitor VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @CAPACITOR_CHILD
    SELECT '2190',  'Film' UNION ALL
    SELECT '3536',  'tantalum' UNION ALL
    SELECT '9999',  'niobium'

DECLARE @INDUCTOR_CHILD TABLE
(
InductorID  VARCHAR (50),
Inductor VARCHAR (50)
)

    SELECT '29',    'air core' UNION ALL
    SELECT '56',    'parasitic' UNION ALL
    SELECT '35',    'Spiderweb'
```

Expected output

```
PowerAmplifierID    PowerAmplifier  AudioAmplifierID    AudioAmplifier  ResistorID  Resistor    CapacitorID Capacitor   InductorID  Inductor    Year

24456   Class A Power Amplifiers    5392    Transconductance    ''  ''  2190    Film    29  air core    1959
24455   Class B Power Amplifiers    4233    Transresistance ''  ''  2190    Film    56  parasitic   1959
```

Thanks a lot...

```
24456   5392        2190    10  1959 -- Invalid InductorID as not available in child table, so remove from output
24456           8888    29  1959-- Invalid CapacitorID as not available in child table,so remove from output
30583   4233        2190    56  1959-- Invalid Poweramplifierid as not available in child table, remove from output
24455   333333      2190    10  1958-- Invalid AudioAmplifierid as not available in child table, remove from output
696969  7879    1xt 5000    29  2015-- Invalid Poweramplifierid as not available in child table, remove from output
24456   5392        2190    29  1959 -- all valid id and resistorid is null so treated as valid record
24455   4233        2190    56  1959 -- all valid id and resistorid is null so treated as valid record
```

Comment: Where is your current query? what do you mean when there is a match to a child? there are 5 child tables, which one?

Comment: I don't understand what this means:  "i need to pull data only when there is an match with child table but any column contain blank ('') in master table that will be treated as valid and appear in the output."   Can you maybe get a native English speaker to help you re-write your question?

Comment: @sagi: in  expected output we can see data from all child table

i tried  using Inner join to get rows when value matched, but not getting expected output.
shall i post my query?, kindly help.

Comment: @TabAlleman: it means blank. i am sorry if it is confusing. i edited the question

Comment: you missed a bit from your original sql:  Insert @INDUCTOR_CHILD

Comment: Your "Expected Output" only contains two rows, but in your problem statement you say you want to include all blanks (nulls?). It sounds like you need to use `FULL OUTER JOIN` to link your tables, but it's really not very clear in the way you've worded your question.

Comment: @JoeMalpass: yes Joe. i am sorry my words are not clear. what i am looking is if any of the ids from Master matched with child, then it should be in output + if value in any column of master is NULL () even those record should be in output. i am trying to filter only invalid id present in master and not in child table.

Comment: @akhrot the answers posted match that criteria - every row from master is inlcuded in the results plus all successful joins.  perhaps you could give an example of a specific row and why it should NOT be in the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what is described about *blanks* but to return rows from `master` and related details (if any) `LEFT JOIN` may be applied:

```
SELECT *
FROM @MASTER m
LEFT JOIN @POWER_CHILD pc on pc.PowerAmplifierID = m.PowerAmplifierID
LEFT JOIN @AUDIO_CHILD ac on ac.AudioAmplifierID = m.AudioAmplifierID
LEFT JOIN @RESISTOR_CHILD  rc on rc.ResistorID = m.ResistorID
LEFT JOIN @CAPACITOR_CHILD cc on cc.CapacitorID = m.CapacitorID
LEFT JOIN @INDUCTOR_CHILD ic on ic.InductorID = m.InductorID
WHERE (m.PowerAmplifierID = '' or pc.PowerAmplifierID is not NULL)
  and (m.AudioAmplifierID = '' or ac.AudioAmplifierID is not NULL)
  and (m.ResistorID = '' or rc.ResistorID is not NULL)
  and (m.CapacitorID = '' or cc.CapacitorID is not NULL)
  and (m.InductorID = '' or ic.InductorID is not NULL)
```

Comment: i think my question is confusing. 1st: when ids matched with respective child table id then only pull records. 2nd: there is no data at all in few columns of master table which i called as blank. i should call it as NULL.Those NULL are good to be appear in the output. i hope it is little clear now

Comment: I think I got it. Check out `WHERE` clause and result matching your request.

Answer (score 1):

Heres my sql - I use multiple left joins and coalesce to replace the nulls.

You could add a where clause to remove completely unmatched lines.

```
select 
m.PowerAmplifierID ,
Coalesce(pc.PowerAmplifier,'') as PowerAmplifier,  

m.AudioAmplifierID , 
Coalesce(ac.AudioAmplifier,'') as AudioAmplifier,   

m.ResistorID  ,
Coalesce(rc.Resistor,'') as Resistor, 

m.CapacitorID ,
Coalesce(cc.Capacitor,'') as Capacitor, 

m.InductorID  ,
Coalesce(ic.InductorID,'') as Inductor, 

m.Years 

from @Master m
left join @Power_Child pc on pc.PowerAmplifierID = m.PowerAmplifierID
left join @Audio_Child ac on ac.AudioAmplifierID = m.AudioAmplifierID
left join @RESISTOR_CHILD rc on rc.ResistorID = m.ResistorID
left join @Capacitor_Child cc on cc.CapacitorID = m.CapacitorID
left join @Inductor_Child ic on ic.InductorID = m.InductorID
```

To Show only rows which have no invalid Id's in the master table add this where clause

```
where 
   not (((m.PowerAmplifierID is not null) and pc.PowerAmplifierID is null)
Or ((m.AudioAmplifierID is not null) and ac.AudioAmplifierID is null)
Or ((m.ResistorID is not null) and rc.ResistorID is null)
Or ((m.CapacitorID is not null) and cc.CapacitorID is null)
Or ((m.InductorID is not null) and ic.InductorID is null))
```

if you want to show only rows which do have an invalid id in @master use this where clause

```
where 
   ((m.PowerAmplifierID is not null) and pc.PowerAmplifierID is null)
Or ((m.AudioAmplifierID is not null) and ac.AudioAmplifierID is null)
Or ((m.ResistorID is not null) and rc.ResistorID is null)
Or ((m.CapacitorID is not null) and cc.CapacitorID is null)
Or ((m.InductorID is not null) and ic.InductorID is null)
```

In the data set you provided all rows in @master have an invalid id

Comment: you are right we can include where and limit the rows. but how can i assure that if there is no value in master (called blank here)
those should not get filter

Comment: Sorry but I'm really not sure what you are asking for here - what is special about the 2 rows listed in your expected results?

Comment: 1st All id from master table matched with their respective child table. 2nd : even some of the resistorid in master table have no value,  than those rows not excluded from output.

Comment: so i am looking only those record whose value match with child.  and if value is not present then also it should present in the output. only those record get excluded if it contain ids which is not present in child table.

Comment: @akhot I've added a choice of where clauses is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i have edited the question with example why record should appear and why it should not. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.PowerAmplifierID
    , COALESCE(p.PowerAmplifier, '')
    , a.AudioAmplifierID
    , COALESCE(a.AudioAmplifier, '')
    , c.CapacitorID
    , COALESCE(c.Capacitor, '')
    , i.InductorID
    , COALESCE(i.Inductor, '')
    , r.ResistorID
    , COALESCE(r.Resistor, '')
    , m.Years
FROM @MASTER m
LEFT JOIN @POWER_CHILD p ON m.PowerAmplifierID = p.PowerAmplifierID
LEFT JOIN @AUDIO_CHILD a ON m.AudioAmplifierID = a.AudioAmplifierID
LEFT JOIN @CAPACITOR_CHILD c ON m.CapacitorID = c.CapacitorID
LEFT JOIN @INDUCTOR_CHILD i ON m.InductorID = i.InductorID
LEFT JOIN @RESISTOR_CHILD r ON m.ResistorID = r.ResistorID
```

`COALESCE` returns a blank string in this case if the field is `NULL`.

Comment: you are right we can include where and limit the rows. but how can i assure that if there is no value in master (called blank here)
those should not get filter

Comment: So you want only those that don't have any value in @RESISTOR_CHILD but all other columns?

Comment: No. i will explain. if any of the id of master match with id of child. then those record to be in output +  and if id itself not present in master . those records must be in output.

Comment: i am sorry my words are not clear. what i am looking is if any of the ids from Master matched with child, then it should be in output + if value in any column of master is NULL () even those record should be in output. i am trying to filter only invalid id present in master and not in child table.